# How to use View elements inside Where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-view

I have this element in my database view :

```
  CASE
    WHEN Type = 'Reserved' THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END AS isReserved,
```

I want to use isReserved column inside my WHERE clause. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Use a subquery, CTE, or repeat the defintion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY ... VALUES` (in SQL Server - didn't notice it wasn't tagged for any specific DBMS)

```
SELECT isReserved
FROM   YourTable
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN Type = 'Reserved' THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
                            ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
                           END)) CA(isReserved)
WHERE  isReserved = 1
```

But you're probably better off just using `Type = 'Reserved'` etc. in your WHERE clause directly rather than referencing the CASE result anyway. That way it is sargable and can use an index.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly.

Either you include a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT <something> as newAlias FROM YourTable) as T
WHERE T.newAlias = ....
```

or just repeat the definition

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE <something> = ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use same expression in where clause, and oracle sql will not calculate it again, it will get result from cache

```
select CASE
    WHEN Type = 'Reserved' THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END AS isReserved
 from tablename
 where CASE
    WHEN Type = 'Reserved' THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END=CAST(0 AS bit)
```